# How can I implement this floating sidebar block?

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm going to implement a floating sidebar block that can contain user's selections. It is a kind of cart. Please check the image below.

If the use press 'Add to my favorite', then it should be contained in the sidebar. 
The floating sidebar block should slide up and down with buttons. Each item of it should be removed if the user press some kind of cross mark at the edge of item. 
After selection, the user can check all the items which have selected using 'View my favorites' button.

What is the right solution to do this? 
I was thinking that I needed to use 'Views module'. But I can't imagine how to make this sidebar slided.

[image]

Comment: Which version of drupal are you using? D7?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Drupal 7!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with [HotBlocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/hotblocks) module, Check out the [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj1O04osAfE)

- Add, remove, and reorder nodes or blocks to a page without leaving or
  reloading the page or using editors
- Content added to hotblocks can be constrained to individual pages or
  be made global to display on all pages that contain the hotblock
- Can display multiple instances of the same block or node in multiple
  regions
- Can give end users the ability to add and remove blocks to pages
  without exposing the administer blocks permission
- Provides a means to filter which of those blocks are available to the
  user for adding so every block in the system is not exposed
- See an overview and administer all of your assigned hotblock content
  grouped by region, url, or taxonomy on a single page
- Allow users to add and remove content to a page without giving them
  permission to edit that content
- Advanced permissioning possible - allows you to control which roles
  can assign/remove/reorder each type of content to every hotblock
  individually if necessary
- You can use your own custom icon set for the UI controls to customize
  look and feel
- If you don't like the term "hotblock" you can customize the
  terminology exposed to the user to suit your purposes

and for floating use [Floating block](https://www.drupal.org/project/floating_block) module.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can achieve that by using the combination of following modules

[Floating block](https://www.drupal.org/project/floating_block)

> The Floating block module allows you to keep html blocks, selected using jquery selectors in a fixed position on the page as you scroll. It works in a similar way the table header fixer in Drupal Core. This means that when the user scrolls their browser selected parts of the page can stay in the users view.

[Close Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/closeblock)

> Close Block - is a module which allows to add a "close" button to any block.

Comment: I really appreciate for your kind comment. I'll check it out right now.